# Get current values inside Sails' Waterline beforeUpdate hook

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js, waterline

In Sails' Waternline I need to be able to compare the previous value with the new one and assign a new attribute under some condition. For example:

```
beforeUpdate: function(newValues, callback) {
   if(/* currentValues */.age > newValues.age) {
     newValues.permission = false;
   }
}
```

How could I access the `currentValues` ?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure this is the best solution but you can get the current record by doing a simple `findOne` request:

```
beforeUpdate: function(newValues, callback) {
  Model
    .findOne(newValues.id)
    .exec(function (err, currentValues) {
      // Handle errors
      // ...

      if(currentValues.age > newValues.age) {
        newValues.permission = false;
      }

      return callback();
    });
}
```

Comment: I was trying to avoid the extra `findOne`, but I guess it will work, thanks !

Comment: Note that this won't work if you're not passing along the `id` for the update or if you're updating multiple records based on criteria in stead of an `id`.